# Find user online time

Tags: sql

Having a question on how to write a self-join query.
The Online Session Table holds all user activities. Each Activity has a State ID, TimeStap to record the User login time.

It's like:
example:

```
State    TimeStamp     User
  X        1300         A
  Y        1700         A
  X        0700         B
  Z        1500         B
  Y        1600         B
  X        2100         C
```

A little Explanation: In the above table, User A logged in State X on 1300, then logged in State Y on 1700, so the User A spend 0400(assume it's 4 hours) in State X. 
The Same logic applied to User B. 
Then User C, since it never change sate, so we use current time - login time stamp of X.

The output should look like:

```
State    Time             User
  X   0400(or 4)           A
  X   0800(or 8)           B
  Z   0100(or 1)           B
  X   result of Now-2100   C
```

### .......

Edit: Just make the problem clearer.Now let's assume it's in SQL Server DMBS,but it's ok to use other DBMS.

And input timestamps are store as default datetime format like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

Comment: This is Microsoft Azure Interview Question. Over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which DBMS you're using, so I'm writing this how I'd do it in MS SQL Server (TSQL).  You'll need access to the `LAG` function, which is not universal.

What `LAG` does is allow you to compare values from a previous row, based on some shared column value, in this case `User`.  This code catches those comparisons in the `prev_` fields.  I'm using `count()` to differentiate users with more than one line from users with only one line.  The single-line users are handled separately after the `union all`.

You'll notice that I'm not using your field names until the final output step.  This is because `State`, `Timestamp` and `User` are all reserved words, i.e. words that do something in SQL code.  I strongly recommend you use field names that are not reserved words.

This code does have a major limitation; it doesn't work for the now-minus-time portion if it's not the same day.  So in your example, it would have to be between 21:01 and 23:59 the same day for it to work.  If you wanted to do this robustly you'd use `datetime` format for your times, which would make this a lot easier and eliminate the limitation.  But this answer is for your data, so:

```
SELECT 
    b.prev_state AS [State]
    ,b.Online_time - b.prev_time AS [Time]
    ,b.U_ID as [User]
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t.Online_state
        ,t.U_ID
        ,t.Online_time
        ,LAG(t.online_time) OVER (PARTITION BY t.U_ID ORDER BY t.U_ID, t.online_time) AS prev_time
        ,LAG(t.online_state) OVER (PARTITION BY t.U_ID ORDER BY t.U_ID, t.online_time) AS prev_state
    FROM online_t AS t
    inner join 
        (SELECT 
            U_ID, 
            count(U_ID) AS tot
        FROM online_t
        GROUP BY U_ID) AS a
        on t.U_ID = a.U_ID
    WHERE tot > 1) AS b
WHERE prev_time is not null

union all

SELECT
    t.Online_state AS [State]
    ,concat(datepart(hh,getdate()),'00') - t.Online_time AS [Time]
    ,t.U_ID AS [USER]
FROM online_t AS t 
inner join
    (SELECT 
        U_ID
        ,count(U_ID) as tot
    FROM online_t
    GROUP BY U_ID) as a
    on t.U_ID = a.U_ID
WHERE tot = 1
```

Comment: Window functions are pretty much "universal" nowadays.

Comment: @RominusWill the same method/logic appied if I store the timestamp as default datetime format, like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?

Comment: The overall logic doesn't change, but the 'concat()' line is specifically to deal with the non-datetime format. With datetime you can skip the transformation and just subtract from the value itself

Comment: Also you wouldn't need the the parts that count 'tot' or anything past the 'union'

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using Oracle analytical functions, which may not be available to you. I'm also using timestamps as oracle varchars.

I'm using LEAD() in a subquery to return the "next user" and the "next time".
Then using a CASE statement to handle the different scenarios.

```
SELECT M.THESTATE,
    CASE 
    WHEN M.USERID = M2.NEXT_USER THEN M2.NEXT_TIME-M.THETIME
    WHEN M.USERID <> M2.NEXT_USER THEN NULL
    ELSE M.THETIME-0 END AS TOTALTIME 
    ,M.USERID
    FROM MYTEST M
    JOIN 
    (
      SELECT USERID, THESTATE, THETIME
      ,LEAD(THETIME) OVER (ORDER BY USERID, THETIME) AS NEXT_TIME
      ,LEAD(USERID) OVER (ORDER BY USERID, THETIME) AS NEXT_USER
      FROM MYTEST
      ORDER BY USERID
    ) M2 ON M2.USERID = M.USERID AND M2.THESTATE=M.THESTATE
    WHERE 
      CASE     
      WHEN M.USERID = M2.NEXT_USER THEN M2.NEXT_TIME-M.THETIME
      WHEN M.USERID <> M2.NEXT_USER THEN NULL
      ELSE M.THETIME-0 END 
    IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Including your input in a WITH clause (I use the TIMESTAMP type for your "timestamp"; and some databases don't like if you use reserved words ("user", "timestamp") for column names), try this:

```
WITH
-- input, don't use in query
input(state,"timestamp","user") AS (
          SELECT 'X',TIMESTAMP '2017-03-15 13:00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Y',TIMESTAMP '2017-03-15 17:00:00','A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',TIMESTAMP '2017-03-15 07:00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Z',TIMESTAMP '2017-03-15 15:00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Y',TIMESTAMP '2017-03-15 16:00:00','B'
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',TIMESTAMP '2017-03-15 21:00:00','C'
)
,
-- start real query here, comma above would 
-- be the WITH keyword
state_duration_user AS (
SELECT
  state
, IFNULL(
    LEAD("timestamp") OVER(ORDER BY "timestamp")
  , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ) - "timestamp"
  AS "time"
, "user"
FROM input
)
SELECT 
  state
, CAST(SUM("time") AS TIME(0)) AS "time"
, "user"    
FROM state_duration_user
GROUP BY
  state
, "user"
;

state|time    |user
Y    |04:00:00|A
Y    |01:00:00|B
Z    |01:00:00|B
X    |02:00:00|A
X    |06:00:00|B
X    |07:59:19|C
```